# "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified aggregate function"

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT SUM(orders.quantity) AS num, fName, surname
FROM author
INNER JOIN book ON author.aID = book.authorID;
```

I keep getting the error message: "you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression "fName" as part of an aggregate function. What do I do?

Comment: You select `SUM(orders.quantity)` but you are joining `author` and `book`. Makes no sense to me. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The error is because `fName` is included in the `SELECT` list, but is not included in a `GROUP BY` clause and is not part of an aggregate function (`Count()`, `Min()`, `Max()`, `Sum()`, etc.)

You can fix that problem by including `fName` in a `GROUP BY`.  But then you will face the same issue with `surname`.  So put both in the `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT
    fName,
    surname,
    Count(*) AS num_rows
FROM
    author
    INNER JOIN book
    ON author.aID = book.authorID;
GROUP BY
    fName,
    surname
```

Note I used `Count(*)` where you wanted `SUM(orders.quantity)`.  However, `orders` isn't included in the `FROM` section of your query, so you must include it before you can `Sum()` one of its fields.

If you have Access available, build the query in the query designer.  It can help you understand what features are possible and apply the correct Access SQL syntax.

Comment: If you are to add all the selected fields into the grouped clause, doesn't that change number of results that are displayed since identical records resulting from any field would be grouped into a single field each time the group by clause groups by each of the specified fields?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking.  If you `SELECT fName, surname` and then `GROUP BY` those fields, the query result set will include one row for each unique combination of `fName` and `surname`.  Is there something else you would want instead?

Comment: If there are two or more similar occurrences of `fName`, then this will be grouped into one row. Then the same will happen with `surname`, In the end you will have lesser rows. How can you avoid that? Am trying to avoid having lesser results coz of using group by

Comment: But that is not the way it works.  Even though `Fred Smith` and `Fred Jones` both have `Fred` as `fName`, the groups are based on the *combination* of `fName` and `surname` ... so that query result set will have separate rows (groups) for those two people.

Comment: What if you had wanted to group using `fName` only but had to include `surname` on the `group by` clause to avoid the error addressed by this OP? Thanks for clarying.

Comment: Then it would have to be just `SELECT fName` and `GROUP BY fName`  If you wanted to also display a `surname` for the `Fred` group, which `surname` should it be ... `Smith` or `Jones`?  You could put `surname` in an aggregate function in the `SELECT` clause ... `Min(surname)` or `Max(surname)` ... but in those cases you still would use just `GROUP BY fName`

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem in a MS-Access query, and I solved it by changing my equivalent `fName` to an "Expression" (as opposed to "Group By" or "Sum").  So long as all of my fields were "Expression", the Access query builder did not require any `Group By` clause at the end.[image]

Comment: I don't understand what this means. On what basis were you summing if this were even allowed. What sql did this generate?

Comment: Further to the comment from @Brad - I just tried the suggested approach and it did not avoid the error. Please edit your answer to show a working example of the SQL statement generated by the Access query builder. (Switch to "SQL View", then copy and paste the SQL code into your answer.)

Comment: I have a screenshot that shows my experience very clearly, but I don't have enough reputation to post.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY can be selected from Total row in query design view in MS Access.
If Total row not shown in design view (as in my case). You can go to SQL View and add GROUP By fname etc. Then Total row will automatically show in design view.
You have to select as Expression in this row for calculated fields.

Comment: Not really an answer to this question, is it? (BTW, to show the Totals row, just click the Totals icon in the query design toolbar.)