# Built in Functions and Grouping is not working in Microsoft Access

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, join, ms-office

I am trying to select from three tables using inner join in Microsoft Access. in one of the fields, i also need to select how many records did it return.

```
SELECT Person.FirstName, Person.LastName, Person.Phone, 
Person.Email,Person.Address, Room.RoomNo, Room.Type, Building.Name, 
Floor.Name,count(*) as result

FROM (Floor INNER JOIN (Building INNER JOIN 
Room ON Building.BuildingID = Room.BuildingID) ON Floor.FloorNo = 
Room.FloorNo) INNER JOIN (Person INNER JOIN Patient ON Person.Username = 
Patient.Username) ON Room.RoomNo = Patient.RoomNo

WHERE (((Person.FirstName) Like "*" & [Forms]![search]![firstnameKey] & "*")
AND ((Person.LastName) Like "*" & [Forms]![search]![lastnameKey] & "*")) AND 
(patient.status = 1)

GROUP BY Patient.username  ;
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: @hypetech your query does not include the specified expression 'FirstName' as part of aggregate function

Answer (score 1):

Any time you have an aggregate function you'll have to `group by` the fields not being calculated. Just from looking at your select statement you are returning multiple fields, i.e: `Person.Firstname, Person.Lastname` etc. I believe you will have to `group by` those non-aggregated fields.

Sample Code:

```
SELECT Person.FirstName, Person.LastName, Person.Phone, Person.Email, Person.Address, Count(*) as Result <br>
From Table1 join table 2 -- etc <br>
WHERE a = b -- etc <BR>
GROUP BY Person.FirstName, Person.LastName, Person.Phone, Person.Email, Person.Address
```

Comment: I used `GROUP BY` for the `COUNT` function

Comment: I've included some sample code in my original answer. It's a basic display of what you should try. You will still have to  group by all the fields I didn't include. Do NOT include the Count(*) as part of your Group By Statement. Hope that helps.

Comment: If you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430500/ HansUp provides a fairly detailed answer to the same issue you are having.

Comment: well, I also implemented it this way. it worked. but, the problem is, the `count` function is not giving me correct results. it's always returning 1

Comment: I'd have to view the tables your looking at as well as the expected output for the query, to be of any use. It seems that now you have to look at the logic behind your query.