# How to get average of a column for 2 different WHERE clauses?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to get the average of a column for 2 different where clauses. Here is what I currently have.

```
SELECT ART_Type,avg(ART_Length) AS AvgLength FROM Articles 
WHERE ART_Type = 'BUS' OR ART_Type = 'LAW' ;
```

I need to get the averages for the ART_Length column, where the ART_Type column is either LAW or BUS.

I also need to display the ART_Type in the first column of the query results.

When I run the code above I get the error:

"Your query does not include the specified expression 'ART_Type' as part of an aggregate function."

Thank you

Comment: `GROUP BY ART_Type` ~ https://support.office.com/en-us/article/GROUP-BY-Clause-84eeb766-25d2-4aa1-8eea-002bb65ef3a0

Comment: You're welcome. Next time, try searching for the error message (leaving out the particulars of your schema such as table / column names). This came up right away for me ~ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430500/ms-access-you-tried-to-execute-a-query-that-does-not-include-the-specified-agg

Comment: @phil that was the first thing I did. I looked at some answers but I didn't know enough to know what they did differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SELECT ART_Type,avg(ART_Length) AS AvgLength 
    FROM Articles WHERE ART_Type = 'BUS' OR ART_Type = 'LAW' 
    GROUP BY ART_Type ;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
GROUP BY ART_Type
```

Thank you Phil