# SQL Query to retrieve Item name and sum of amounts for that item

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access table that has daily expenses entered through a Form. I would like to show a summary table in the same form showing total expenses for each expense category. The access table has the following columns:

```
    Date
    Item (Category)
    Amount
```

I would like to query the table and display the top 10 expenses for the current month.

I tried using the following:

```
    Select Item, Sum([Amount]) from Expenses where Date >= #2/1/2016 
    ORDER BY Sum([Amount]) DESC
```

.. but doesn't work

Can anyone suggest the right method to use this statement?

Comment: try `Select Item, Sum([Amount]) from Expenses where Date >= #2/1/2016# GROUP BY Item ORDER BY Sum([Amount]) DESC`.  It has been a while so I do not guarantee it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS-Access - you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified aggregate function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430500/ms-access-you-tried-to-execute-a-query-that-does-not-include-the-specified-agg)

Comment: ^^ that one, I bet. In addition, **Date** is a reserved word, and you must put it into brackets **[Date]**, or better, rename your column.

Comment: Yes I used Date in [] also modified the query to as follows and it did the trick:
Select [Item], Sum([Amount]) AS TotAmount from Cumulative_Expenses where " & "[Date] Between " & startDate & " and " & endDate & "GROUP BY [Item] ORDER BY Sum([Amount]) DESC