# SQL,Nested Queries (MS ACCESS)

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I am trying to tackle a problem but seem to be getting nowhere. I want to display Grade 12 students who scored below average for Maths then instead of displaying their average display their maths marks instead.

I am using msAccess and suspect the use of nested queries are necessary.The fields I am working with are first_name, last_name, grade (from 1 to 12) and Maths (containing maths marks)

I have this:

```
Select first_name,last_name,maths
FROM students
WHERE grade = 12
HAVING ROUND(AVG(maths),1)< maths;
```

Output:

Error:
You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'first_name' as part of an aggregate function

However, I do not know why it is throwing this error and it repeats like this even after removing the field from select which I don't want to do in the first place because I need to display it

Comment: Please read and act on [mcve]. Give all relevant code, input, output, desired output and error messages.

Comment: I have provided context, fields, expected result and the code causing the problem what more can I add? @philipxy

Comment: Read about HAVING. It is used with GROUP BY. When there's no explicit GROUP BY, it's as if you had written a certain default one. Since grouping partitions a table into groups of rows per one subrow value for specified columns, one can only SELECT from among those columns, because there are lots of rows with different values for the other columns. PS If you gave the error number & message, you could probably get your answer by googling right away.

Comment: I have updated the question, thank you for the input I'll look into it @philipxy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS-Access - you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified aggregate function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430500/ms-access-you-tried-to-execute-a-query-that-does-not-include-the-specified-agg)

Comment: Re getting to the query that is your goal, 1. find out the difference between the AVG of a column for a group vs a whole table. (You've written the former but want the latter.) Start by writing a query that returns a person's math mark and the average math mark. Then maybe math marks that are equal to the average. Do you *need* to GROUP BY?

Comment: If you want to do it "the Access way" (meaning the GUI): Create a query with the `averages_per_grade` (which will use `group by`), and another `averages_per_student_and_grade` (which we'll use *different* `group by`, the grade is just there to simplify things). Joining both on `grade` you can easily compare students "below_average" with the adequate `WHERE` ... at this point, you're 2/3 of the way. You are actually not using the term `HAVING` (although you use the concept implicitly)

Comment: @philipxy: I assumed the marks are the result of several tests, and that you have *several* math marks per student... If that's not the case, you're right about the sencod grouping (it would be useless, because it would return the same as not grouping by, but not harmful). Without knowing the table definitions... it's a bit difficult to decide.

Comment: Please edit your question with the finished version of the following sentence: "A row (first_name, last_name, maths, grade, ...?) is in Maths if and only if student *first_name* *last_name* got grade *grade* in ...?" (See joanolo's comment abut not knowing what you are putting in your tables hence not knowing how to get something out.) Then do the same for the table that is the result of your query.

Answer (score 0):

To get the users who scored below the average, you can do a query similar to yours, but with a `group by`:

```
select s.student_id, avg(maths) as avg_maths
from students as s
where s.grade = 12
group by s.student_id
having avg(maths) < (select avg(maths) from students where grade = 12);
```

(Note:  This assumes that you have an id for each student, rather than using the name.)

Next, you can get the original maths scores in various ways.  One simple way uses `in`:

```
select first_name, last_name, maths
from students
where grade = 12 and
      student_id in (select s.student_id, avg(s.maths) as avg_maths
                     from students as s
                     where s.grade = 12
                     group by s.student_id
                     having avg(maths) < (select avg(maths) from students where grade = 12)
                    );
```