# Ordering By a Group By Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm trying to perform a query to display results that are *grouped by* Supplier (`Supp_Code`), then within each group, the results are *ordered by* Commission Code (`Comm_Code`).

The following query:

```
sql = "SELECT [Comm_Code], [Supp_Code], [AqYear], [Product_Code], [Type], [Customer_Code], " & _
      "[Commission_Rate], [cType] FROM [Acquisition Commission] GROUP BY [Supp_Code] " & _
      "ORDER BY [Comm_Code]"

Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)

Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable

da.Fill(ds)
```

Gives an error:

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Comm_Code' as part of an aggregate function.

I looked this up and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19431046/6530111) says it's because I'm including the `Comm_Code` in the `SELECT` but not the `GROUP BY`.

So, I changed it to:

```
sql = "SELECT [Comm_Code], [Supp_Code], [AqYear], [Product_Code], [Type], [Customer_Code], " & _
      "[Commission_Rate], [cType] FROM [Acquisition Commission] GROUP BY [Supp_Code] " & _
      "ORDER BY [Comm_Code]"
```

But then I got the same error, but with the `AqYear` field.

This is going to continue until I've included all of the selected fields in the `GROUP BY` clause... Surely this will give me the wrong output, but even if not, it seems a lot of unnecessary querying.

Is there a faster/better way to achieve what I'm looking to do? Or do I need to just include every query in the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: You're not doing any grouping with your statement. If you just want them to be ordered together, add them on the order by clause.

Comment: When you group by Supp_Code, you get one result row per Supp_Code. As there can be many records for one Supp_Code in the table, which of its Comm_Codes, which of its AqYears, which of its Product_Codes, etc. do you want to see in the result row? You need to specify this, e.g. MAX(Comm_Code), MIN(AqYear), ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are just looking for a non-aggregated query with two `ORDER BY` keys:

```
SELECT [Comm_Code], [Supp_Code], [AqYear], [Product_Code], [Type], [Customer_Code], 
       [Commission_Rate], [cType]
FROM [Acquisition Commission] 
ORDER BY [Supp_Code], [Comm_Code];
```

A query with `GROUP BY` would normally have aggregation functions such as `COUNT()` or `SUM()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- group by Id & order by Name

    SELECT  id, name, dob  FROM  test  GROUP BY  id   ORDER BY  name
```

try something like this..

Cheers!!