# Selecting columns & counting in a SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, count

For each customer I need to list the `CUS_CODE`, the number of customers in each area `(CUS_AREACODE)` and the total balance `(CUS_BALANCE)` and group those records by the `CUS_BALANCE`.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT (CUS_AREACODE) AS CUSTOMERS_IN_AREA, 
    CUS_CODE, CUS_BALANCE
FROM 
    CUSTOMER
GROUP BY 
    CUS_BALANCE;
```

I'm pretty new to SQL and i receive an error saying that

> CUS_CODE isn't an aggregate function

and I'm not entirely sure what that means and why.

Comment: Please add the database you're using.for i.e. Oracle,MySQL etc.

Comment: Do you just want to display the CUS_BALANCE or want sum of CUS_BALANCE?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS-Access - you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430500/ms-access-you-tried-to-execute-a-query-that-does-not-include-the-specified-agg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule of `GROUP BY`, same column list MUST be present in `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clause. You are missing `CUS_CODE` in `GROUP BY`.

```
GROUP BY CUS_BALANCE, CUS_CODE;
```

instead of

```
GROUP BY CUS_BALANCE;
```