# Your Query does not include the expression 'Open Amount' as part of an aggerate function - MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT [doc type], [Open Amount]
     , [customer number]
     , COUNT([customer number]) As CountCustomerNumber
     , SUM(IIF([Open Amount]>'0', [Open Amount], 0)) AS sum_open_amount_pos   
     , SUM(IIF([Open Amount]<'0', [Open Amount], 0)) As sum_open_amount_neg         
FROM 
      (SELECT d.[customer number] & d.[membership number] AS CustMemb
            , d.[customer number]
            , agg.[Open Amount]
            , agg.[doc type]
            , SUM(agg.[Open Amount]) AS SumOpenAmount
        FROM  (SELECT [doc type]
                    , [customer number]
                    , SUM([Open Amount]) AS TotalSubOpenAmount
               FROM   data
               WHERE  [doc type] = 'RU' 
               GROUP BY [doc type]
                      , [customer number]
              ) agg
        INNER JOIN [data] d                                   
           ON  d.[customer number] = agg.[customer number]
        GROUP  BY d.[customer number] & d.[membership number]
                , d.[customer number]
                , agg.[doc type]
                , agg.[Open Amount]
      ) AS sub
GROUP  BY [doc type]
        , [customer number]
        , [Open Amount]
HAVING COUNT([customer number]) = 1
```

---

Added Open Amount to Group BY Clause - Looking for parameter value for agg.Open Amount -----------------------------------------

Comment: In you sub-SELECTs, you are summing `[Open Amount]`, but ignoring that result and summing "Open Amount" again in the outer query. Did you want to sum that summed subresult?

Comment: No I am just looking to bring back these two results for every customer Number:      , SUM(IIF([Open Amount]>'0', [Open Amount], 0)) AS sum_open_amount_pos   
     , SUM(IIF([Open Amount]<'0', [Open Amount], 0)) As sum_open_amount_neg

Comment: Nitpick: `[Open Amount]>'0'` - why not `[Open Amount]> 0 ` (0 should be a numerical value, not a string)

Comment: Thank you - That is correct

Answer (score 0):

See the following stackoverflow post: [“You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified aggregate function”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430500/you-tried-to-execute-a-query-that-does-not-include-the-specified-aggregate-func). I think you just need to add `[Open Amount]` to the final `GROUP BY`

```
  .
  . 
  .
GROUP  BY [doc type]
        , [customer number]
        , [Open Amount]
HAVING COUNT([customer number]) = 1
```

???

Answer (score 0):

You have three elements in you select that are not part of any aggregation but only two elements in your group by, that is why you get the error message.

When you use aggregation function, all the non aggregated elements of the select need to be in the group by hence your query become like this :

EDIT :  You are selecting [Open Amount] and aggregating SUM(agg.[Open Amount]) AS SumOpenAmount in your sub query.

You are also doing something similar in your external query

```
SELECT [doc type], [Open Amount]
     , [customer number]
     , COUNT([customer number]) As CountCustomerNumber
     , SUM(IIF([Open Amount]>'0', [Open Amount], 0)) AS sum_open_amount_pos   
     , SUM(IIF([Open Amount]<'0', [Open Amount], 0)) As sum_open_amount_neg         
FROM SubQueries
GROUP  BY [doc type]
          [Open Amount]
        , [customer number]
HAVING COUNT([customer number]) = 1
```

Should be something like that :

```
SELECT [doc type]
         , [customer number]
         , COUNT([customer number]) As CountCustomerNumber
         , SUM(IIF([Open Amount]>'0', [Open Amount], 0)) AS sum_open_amount_pos   
         , SUM(IIF([Open Amount]<'0', [Open Amount], 0)) As sum_open_amount_neg         
    FROM SubQueries
    GROUP  BY [doc type]
            , [customer number]
    HAVING COUNT([customer number]) = 1
```

Comment: In your most down sub-select you try to group by [Open Amount] but this is in an aggregated function in your select

Comment: Thanks for that. Edited. Still brining backing the same parameter query however

Comment: In the above query you are selecting agg.[Open Amount] and also SUM(agg.[Open Amount]) AS SumOpenAmount
Edited post accordingly

Answer (score 0):

When you *sum over* `[Open Amount]`, you cannot also select each separate "Open Amount". So remove it from both "SELECT" and "GROUP BY":

```sql
SELECT [doc type] --, [Open Amount]
     , [customer number]
     --, COUNT([customer number]) As CountCustomerNumber
     , SUM(IIF([Open Amount]>'0', [Open Amount], 0)) AS sum_open_amount_pos   
     , SUM(IIF([Open Amount]<'0', [Open Amount], 0)) As sum_open_amount_neg         
FROM 
-- snip
GROUP  BY [doc type]
        , [customer number]
        -- , [Open Amount]
-- snip
```

And similarly, if you group by "Customer Number", a `Count([Customer Number])` would return 1 (if it worked).