# How to display overall count of rows in a database in vb.net CHART Y AXIS

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

> Edit i tried the RecCount from Hel o Ween's comment and it showed this exception [RecCount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWb4C.png)

Heres my code, the x axis is working but the y axis show this error :[Exception of Y axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBcA6.png)

> Im trying to make the x axis with all the same value in a specific column.
> And y axis as the overall counts of rows in a database

```
        Dim READER As OleDbDataReader
        Try

            Dim query As String
            query = "SELECT ID, purok  FROM Household"
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
            READER = cmd.ExecuteReader
            Dim dT As New DataTable
            dT.Load(READER)


            Dim counter As String
            counter = dT.Rows.Count.ToString


            'Dim countrow = Convert.ToInt16(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
            'Label3.Text = countrow
            Chart1.Series("Purok").XValueMember = "Purok"
            Chart1.Series("Purok").YValueMembers = counter
            Chart1.DataSource = dT
            Chart1.DataBind()

            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Comment: I think instead of Counter you need to give one of column id of your datasource to YValueMember

Comment: It doesn't seem to be too useful to chart Id and Purok. I think they are asking for column names from your DataSource. You need to rethink this. Draw a simulation of your graph by hand to see how your data fits in. Your data access code is far from best practices. Check a few tutorials.

Comment: If you need a row count, modify your SQL statement, e.g. `"SELECT ID, purok, COUNT(*) As RecCount FROM Household"`. If @Mary is right and `.YValueMembers` expects a (database) column name, then assign it "RecCount".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Hel O'Ween's comment and this thread: ["You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified aggregate function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430500/you-tried-to-execute-a-query-that-does-not-include-the-specified-aggregate-func) its fixed now. I just tweaked and added GROUP BY after the FROM statement.

[Heres the result chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLZc4.png)

```
Dim READER As OleDbDataReader
        Try

            Dim query As String
            query = "SELECT purok, COUNT(*) As RecCount FROM Household GROUP BY purok"
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
            READER = cmd.ExecuteReader
            Dim dT As New DataTable
            dT.Load(READER)


          
            Chart1.Series("Purok").XValueMember = "purok"
            Chart1.Series("Purok").YValueMembers = "RecCount"
            Chart1.DataSource = dT
            Chart1.DataBind()

            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
```